# make smartparens not to override python bindings

Tags: key-bindings

with smartparens turned on, `C-M-a` becomes `sp-backward-down-sexp`

I think python-mode's `beginning-of-defun` is more useful.

How I can setup so that

python-mode's keybinding is not overriden by smartparens?

Comment: Minor-mode key bindings override major-mode bindings. Maybe change or remove the binding from the minor-mode keymap.

Comment: "*I think python-mode's `beginning-of-defun` is more useful.*" -- But `beginning-of-defun` is not defined in `python.el`. `beginning-of-defun-function`?

Comment: @shynur I think python mode binds beginning-of-defun-function (which is exposed by more emacs-coreish package) to the python specific navigate-to-beginning-of-defun